# Failed to echo values of variable inside "for loop"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I was writing up a bash script to collect hardware information of each servers. But at some portion of the script I am unable to print values of variable that is given multiple times in a single echo command

```
#!/bin/bash
NO=$(df -hT | grep ext | wc -l)
for i in $(seq 1 $NO);do export PART$i=$(df -hT | grep ext | head -$i | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'); done
echo "Total $NO ext partitions found"
for i in $(seq 1 $NO);do echo "Ext Partition$i is ${PART$i} ";done
```

In my system, I have two ext partitions, so variable $NO would store value 2.

The output I expect and wanted is as follows:

```
Total 2 ext partitions found
Ext Partition1 is /dev/sda7 
Ext Partition2 is /dev/sda8
```

But I am having trouble printing "$PART$i" as expected. Right now I am getting error for "for loop" in last line.

```
# /root/disk.sh
Total 2 ext partitions found
/root/disk.sh: line 5: Ext Partition$i is ${PART$i} : bad substitution
```

Can you tell me how to correctly invoke and echo the value of PART1 and PART2 in last for loop?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use indirect expansion:

```
v=PART$i
echo "Ext Partition$i is ${!v}"
```

From the bash manual:

> If the first character of `parameter` is an exclamation point (!), it introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of `parameter` as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of `parameter` itself. This is known as *indirect expansion*. The exceptions to this are the expansions of `${!prefix*}` and `${!name[@]}` described below. The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.

Comment: It works. But can you tell what does that exclamation mark mean and what is actually does >> ${!v} ?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using an array variable instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
NO=$(df -hT | grep ext | wc -l)
declare -a PART
for i in $(seq 1 $NO);do PART[$i]=$(df -hT | grep ext | head -$i | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'); done
echo "Total $NO ext partitions found"
for i in $(seq 1 $NO);do echo "Ext Partion$i is ${PART[$i]} ";done
```

You could further simplify this code as:

```
PART=( $(df -hT | awk '/ext/ { print $1 }') )
NO=${#PART[@]}
echo "Total $NO ext partitions found"
for i in ${!PART[@]}; do echo "Ext Partion$i is ${PART[$i]} "; done
```

Note that the simplification does change the indexing to be 0-based indexing.

Comment: thank you so much. First one is working fine for me.
For second one, the last for loop "for i in ${!x[@]}; do echo "Ext Partion$i is ${PART[$i]} "; done" print nothing on screen.

Comment: @johnwilson Oops forgot to change my test variable `x` back to `PART` in the second example hehe :) Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @johnwilson The `${!PART[@]}` is not indirect expansion in this case. That is syntax to return the keys of the array i.e. the indexes.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to call ${PART$i} which is two separate variables. Try:

```
echo "Ext Partition$i is ${PART}${i}"
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that one already, but it prints only the value of counter i in each iteration like as follows:
<code>
# /root/disk.sh
Total 2 ext partitions found
Ext Partion1 is 1
Ext Partion2 is 2
</code>